# vsprintf failing

Tags: c, microcontroller, printf

I'm writing C code for a HCS12 microcontroller to interface with an LCD screen as part of an assignment for Uni, and I have a problem where if I try to make a printf wrapper with vsprintf, an exception occurs and the controller goes into a unusable state.

```
void printfLCD(const char *fmt, ...) {
    char buffer[256];
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    (void)vsprintf(buffer, fmt, args);
    putsLCD(buffer);
    va_end(args);
}
```

Stepping through the debugging I can see that it crashes somewhere in vprintf, but I still don't know why.
How can I get this working?

Comment: It can crash simply because the format string and/or variadic arguments are incorrect. But you are not showing them. Show us how you call your `printfLCD` (the crashing call specifically).

Comment: If possible, I recommend you to use `vsnprintf` instead, as that will make sure that you do not overwrite your buffer.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Good advice, but being that this is an embedded microcontroller implementation, there's a good chance it's C89-only...

Comment: it will crash on anything, both `printf("number is %i", 42);` and `printf("hello world");`

Comment: It seems to be a general problem with the standard library supplied by the compiler, if no `printf`-type calls work.

Comment: Sorry, printf does work with TermIO, however I meant to say above `printfLCD` or `vsprintf`.

Answer (score 0):

Is your buffer on the stack?  Some compilers (like the Keil ones) will assume you don't want reentrancy and put local variables out in data space.  However, if it on the stack, it maybe too large.  You might want to make buffer `static` and see if that helps.